# Correr codigos de javascript en VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

No se como correr codigos de javascript directamente desde VS code (visual studio code), es decir, sin necesidad de abrir la consola. Lo habia hecho con python usando la terminal, pero no se como es esa misma funcion para javascript.

Comment: Hola. A lo mejor te sirve esto: https://quokkajs.com/docs/index.html Generalmente javascript corre en el navegador o en nodejs, no es como python que tiene un intérprete (hasta donde se)

Comment: si tienes instalado node puedes abrir la terminal y ejecutar `node fichero.js`

Comment: Te recomiendo instalar el plugin [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).
Una vez instalado, para ejecutar el código: Ctrl+Alt+N.

Comment: hay muchas maneras de hacer eso... el problema es que estas buscando sujerencias o opiniones de como hacer algo y no has realizado una investigacion previa; este tipo de post son mal recibidos ...

Comment: te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Code Runner es una extension para eso, googlealo